# Hadamard product operator norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

suppose that $A$ and $B$ be $n×n$ nonnegative matrices. Consider the operator (spectral) norm on $A$
$\lVert A \rVert_{op} = sup_{x \ne 0} \dfrac{\lVert Ax \rVert}{\lVert x \rVert}= sup_{\lVert x \rVert=1} \lVert Ax \rVert.$

Then $ \lVert A \circ B \rVert _{op} ≤ \rho (A^{T} B)$?

where $\rho (A)$ spectral radius and $A \circ B=( a_{ij}  b_{ij})$ is a the Hadamard product.
I know that
$\rho (A \circ B ) ≤ \rho (AB),$  and $(A \circ B)(B \circ A) ≤  AB \circ BA$.

Comment: Are you asking for the operator norm of the linear operator of Hadamard multiplication by a matrix?

Comment: "Empirically" speaking, the statement seems to hold for randomly generated examples.

Comment: Where are you getting the inequality $\|A \circ B\|_{op} \leq \|A\|_{op} \cdot \|B\|_{op}$? This isn't any version of the "Cauchy Schwarz inequality", contrary to your claim

Comment: @AliAbdAubad Where does the result $\rho(A \circ B) \leq \rho(AB)$ come from? If you have a reference, I'd be interested.

Comment: Matrix Theory Basic Results and Techniques book by Fuzhen Zhang.page 166

Answer (score 3):

Observe that $(A\circ B)^T(A\circ B)\le(A^TB)\circ(B^TA)$ entrywise:
$$
\begin{align}
\big((A\circ B)^T(A\circ B)\big)_{ij}
&=\sum_k\big((A\circ B)^T\big)_{ik}(A\circ B)_{kj}\\
&=\sum_k(A\circ B)_{ki}(A\circ B)_{kj}\\
&=\sum_ka_{ki}b_{ki}a_{kj}b_{kj}\\
&\le\big(\sum_ka_{ki}b_{kj}\big)\big(\sum_kb_{ki}a_{kj}\big)\\
&=(A^TB)_{ij}(B^TA)_{ij}\\
&=\big((A^TB)\circ(B^TA)\big)_{ij}.\tag{0}
\end{align}
$$
It follows that
$$
\|A\circ B\|_2^2
=\rho\big((A\circ B)^T(A\circ B)\big) \le\rho\big((A^TB)\circ(B^TA)\big)
\le\rho(A^TB)\rho(B^TA) =\rho(A^TB)^2.\tag{1}
$$
The first inequality on $(1)$ is true because
$$
0\le X\le Y
\ \Rightarrow\ \forall k\in\mathbb N,\,X^k\le Y^k
\ \Rightarrow\ \rho(X)=\lim_{k\to\infty}\|X^k\|_F^{1/k}\le \lim_{k\to\infty}\|Y^k\|_F^{1/k}=\rho(Y)
$$
by Gelfand's formula. The second inequality is due to the fact when $X$ and $Y$ are square matrices, $X\circ Y$ is a principal submatrix of $X\otimes Y$. Therefore, when $X$ and $Y$ are nonnegative, if $Z$ is the matrix obtained by zeroing out all elements in $X\otimes Y$ outside this principal submatrix, then $0\le Z\le X\otimes Y$ and hence
$$
\rho(X\circ Y)=\rho(Z)\le\rho(X\otimes Y)=\rho(X)\rho(Y).
$$

**Update:** a literature review reveals that this result was proved using a different argument as corollary 6 in Zejun Huang, *On the spectral radius and the spectral norm of Hadamard products of nonnegative matrices*, LAA 434 (2011):457-462. A proof along the same line as my answer but presented in a more general manner was given in corollary 2.3 in Dongjun Chen and Fun Zhang, *On the spectral radius of Hadamard products of nonnegative matrices*, Banach J. Math. Anal. 9(2015), no. 2, 127-133. One interesting observation of the authors is the following inequality for nonnegative matrices:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&(A_{11}\circ A_{21}\circ\cdots\circ A_{s1})(A_{12}\circ A_{22}\circ\cdots\circ A_{s2})\cdots(A_{1t}\circ A_{2t}\circ\cdots\circ A_{st})\\
\le\,&(A_{11}A_{12}\cdots A_{1t})\circ
(A_{21}A_{22}\cdots A_{2t})\circ\cdots\circ
(A_{s1}A_{s2}\cdots A_{st}).
\end{aligned}
$$
In particular, then inequality $(0)$ in my answer can be easily obtained as a special case:
$$
(A\circ B)^T(A\circ B)
=(A^T\circ B^T)(B\circ A)
\le(A^TB)\circ(B^TA).
$$